# Collecting from Flow in UI with repeatOnLifeCycle

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I started to replace `LiveData` with `Flow` since it is more flexible. But then I find out you need to write enormous amount of boilerplate code to observe from `Flow` in UI.

In the [StateFlow documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#livedata), it says that

> `LiveData.observe()` automatically unregisters the consumer when the view goes to the `STOPPED` state, whereas collecting from a `StateFlow` or any other flow does not stop collecting automatically. To achieve the same behavior,you need to collect the flow from a `Lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle` block.

It's also mentioned in the [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda) by Manuel Vivo that using collecting from `lifecycleScope.launchWhenX` is dangerous and should not be used in UI because the producer flow will not stop emitting.

He recommended us to use

```
// Listen to multiple flows
lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        // As collect is a suspend function, if you want to collect
        // multiple flows in parallel, you need to do so in 
        // different coroutines
        launch {
            flow1.collect { /* Do something */ }   
        }
                
        launch {
            flow2.collect { /* Do something */ }
        }
    }   
}
```

The amount of boilerplate code is too much. Is it not possible to do it in a two liner like what `LiveData` does?

```
viewModel.movieData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    ...
}
```

Why is it so complex to collect from `Flow` in UI? Is it advisable to convert the Flow to LiveData with `asLiveData()`?

Answer (score 1):

First answer your first question: `Flow` is a cold flow. And Flow is stateless. If you provide `Flow`, then it means that you need to construct and collect Flow frequently.

In another case, if Hot Flow is provided, such as (StateFlow), although the hot flow provides state (`.value`), it does not know anything about the life cycle of Android. As you said, you can use `launchWhenXXX()` to collect Flow.

When using launchWhenXXX(), you must pay attention to the life cycle of the hot flow. When to start `collect` and when to end `collect`, these need to be paid attention to. So it seems very troublesome. Of course, Flow is a way to get rid of using LiveData.

For details, please refer to: https://proandroiddev.com/should-we-choose-kotlins-stateflow-or-sharedflow-to-substitute-for-android-s-livedata-2d69f2bd6fa5

The second question: LiveData manages the life cycle of Android. `Flow.asLiveData()` is completely desirable. At this time, only a simple Observe is needed.

Comment: `When to start collect and when to end collect`. Almost seems like I'm back to the old Rx days where I need to dispose of subscriptions manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could build extensions to reduce the boilerplate

```
inline fun <T> Flow<T>.collectIn(
    owner: LifecycleOwner,
    minActiveState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
    coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    crossinline action: suspend CoroutineScope.(T) -> Unit
) = owner.addRepeatingJob(minActiveState, coroutineContext) {
    collect {
        action(it)
    }
}
```

This makes collecting flows similar to LiveData as

```
flow.collectIn(viewLifecycleOwner){ /* do stuff */ }
```